# Installing games to other drive

Tags: partitioning, software-installation, ssd, playonlinux

still pretty new to Ubuntu.

I have a 22.2 GB SSD and a 250 GB SSD. Ubuntu and boot stuff is mounted to the little SSD. I think. Now I want to play Skyrim, and PlayOnLinux gets me pretty far into the process, but when it comes time to install, it says I have 4.2 GB free when I need around 8 GB. I don't think I can reduce my usage on the little drive any further, but I can't figure out how to get it to install on the bigger drive, which has 200 GB free. How can I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1):

You can move /home to you second SSD. This will also include Steam and PlayOnLinux games. They are normally installed in /home/[user]/.[application]. Edit `/etc/fstab` for automount on boot:
`UUID=[UUID] /home           ext4    defaults        0       2`

Comment: I used the file manager to click the home folder and drag it to the 250 GB drive, and now it says it's copying all the files over. I went to /etc/fstab and found that it already had the 250 GB SSD's UUID for /home ext4 defaults 0 2. Am I on the right track?

Comment: @VJC did it work?